Nameinlink and \crefmultiformat avoid hyperlinks in figure names
I'm making my document and the language is spanish so when I use cleveref package, this is too useful because, among other things, allows me include the hyperlink of a figure in the whole name (e.g. "figure 1" has the whole hyperlink and not only "1").
This is a MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{color0}{RGB}{0,0,0} 
\colorlet{color1}{green!50!black} 
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{16,131,16} %}
\definecolor{doc}{RGB}{38,111,82}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    %   hidelinks,
    colorlinks,
    breaklinks=true,
    urlcolor=red!50!black,
    citecolor=green!50!black,
    linkcolor= color1,
    bookmarksopen=false,
}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\crefmultiformat{figure}
%{\color{green!50!black}\textbf{figuras} \textbf{#2#1#3}}%
%{ y \textbf{#2#1#3}}%
%{, \textbf{#2#1#3}}%
%{ y \textbf{#2#1#3}}

\crefname{figure}{\textbf{figura}}{\textbf{figuras}}
\Crefname{figure}{\textbf{Figura}}{\textbf{Figuras}}
\addto\extraspanish{%
    \def\figureautorefname{figura}%
    \def\figurecrefname{figura}{figuras}%
    \def\crefrangeconjunction{ al~}%
    \def\crefpairconjunction{ y~}%
    \def\crefmulticjunction{\crefpairconjunction}%
}

\begin{document}
    
    These are references to figures:

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \cref{fig:example}
        \item \cref{fig:example,fig:example2}.
        \item \cref{fig:example,fig:example2,fig:example3}.
        \item \cref{fig:example,fig:example2,fig:example4}.
    \end{itemize}
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \rule{4cm}{4cm} % Una figura ficticia
        \caption{Esta es una figura de ejemplo.}
        \label{fig:example}
    \end{figure}
    
    \newpage
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \rule{4cm}{4cm} % Una figura ficticia
        \caption{This is an example image.}
        \label{fig:example2}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \rule{4cm}{4cm} % Una figura ficticia
        \caption{Esta es una figura de ejemplo.}
        \label{fig:example3}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \rule{4cm}{4cm} % Una figura ficticia
        \caption{Esta es una figura de ejemplo.}
        \label{fig:example4}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}


When I don´t use \crefmultiformat, the expected behavior is fine, but when I use it, only "1" is affected by the hyperlink and not "figure". I know that when there are multiple figures and i want a cross reference, in "figure 1 and 2" only the hyperlink for 1 is put in "figure" and that's fine.
I need the conjunction words in the images ("to" for a range, "and") but in spanish ("al", "y" or comma). I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance :D

Don't reinvent the wheel. Instead, just add spanish to the list of options passed to cleveref. I.e., change \usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} to \usepackage[nameinlink,spanish]{cleveref}.
Upon making this change to your code and commenting out (or deleting) the subsequent instructions in the preamble, one gets:

Note that this change will not render the labels and figure numbers in bold. I think that's all for the better, actually, as readers tend to perceive quickly that typesetting stuff in bold is the equivalent of being shouted at needlessly. Do you want to be the person whose papers are remembered by readers as "why, oh why did the author feel it was ok to shout at us incessantly?", or would you rather be someone whose papers are remembered as being written clearly, concisely, and easy to understand? Making the cross-references into green-colored hyperlinks will be memorable enough, really. Put differently, don't get carried away when creating cross-references.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \fi
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{color0}{RGB}{0,0,0} 
\colorlet{color1}{green!50!black} 
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{16,131,16} %}
\definecolor{doc}{RGB}{38,111,82}

\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    %   hidelinks,
    colorlinks,
    %breaklinks=true,
    urlcolor=red!50!black,
    citecolor=green!50!black,
    linkcolor= color1,
    bookmarksopen=false,
}
\usepackage[nameinlink,spanish]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    
    These are references to figures:

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \cref{fig:example}
        \item \cref{fig:example,fig:example2}.
        \item \cref{fig:example,fig:example2,fig:example3}.
        \item \cref{fig:example,fig:example2,fig:example4}.
    \end{itemize}
    
% streamlining the remaining code...
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:example} 
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:example2}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:example3}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:example4}
    
\end{document}


Addendum to address the OP's follow-up comments and question: If you want both bold-facing and colored hyperlinks, you need to go through the steps explained in section 8.2, "Low-Level Customisation: Taking Full Control", of the cleveref user guide.
Here's how I would implement your formatting choices. Note that for the \crefformat and \crefmultiformat commands, you mustn't write \textbf{figura[s]}~\textbf{#2#1#3} or \textbf{figura[s]~#2#1#3}; it's got to be #2\textbf{figura[s]~#1}#3. (I.e., the #2 and #3 markers mustn't be included in the scope of \textbf.) And, do be sure to wrap the a, y, and , ("comma") particles of the \crefrangeformat and \crefmultiformat directives in \textcolor{black}{...} statements.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \fi
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{color0}{RGB}{0,0,0} 
\colorlet{color1}{green!50!black} 
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{16,131,16} %}
\definecolor{doc}{RGB}{38,111,82}

\usepackage{xurl} % allow long URL strings to break at all locations
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    %hidelinks, % not useful if 'colorlinks' option is set
    colorlinks,
    %breaklinks=true,
    urlcolor=red!50!black,
    citecolor=green!50!black,
    linkcolor= color1,
    bookmarksopen=false,
    }

\usepackage[nameinlink,spanish]{cleveref}
\crefformat{figure}{%
   \color{green!50!black}#2\textbf{figura~#1}#3}
\Crefformat{figure}{%
   \color{green!50!black}#2\textbf{Figura~#1}#3}
\crefrangeformat{figure}{%
   \color{green!50!black}#3\textbf{figuras~#1}#4 %
   \textcolor{black}{a}~#5\textbf{#2}#6}
\Crefrangeformat{figure}{%
   \color{green!50!black}#3\textbf{Figuras~#1}#4 %
   \textcolor{black}{a}~#5\textbf{#2}#6}
\crefmultiformat{figure}%
  {\color{green!50!black}#2\textbf{figuras~#1}#3}%
  { \textcolor{black}{y}~#2\textbf{#1}#3}%
  {\textcolor{black}{,} #2\textbf{#1}#3}%
  { \textcolor{black}{y}~#2\textbf{#1}#3}
\Crefmultiformat{figure}%
  {\color{green!50!black}#2\textbf{Figuras~#1}#3}%
  { \textcolor{black}{y}~#2\textbf{#1}#3}%
  {\textcolor{black}{,} #2\textbf{#1}#3}%
  { \textcolor{black}{y}~#2\textbf{#1}#3}

\begin{document}
    
    These are cross-references to figures:

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \cref{fig:example}; 
              \Cref{fig:example}.
        \item \crefrange{fig:example}{fig:example3};
              \Crefrange{fig:example}{fig:example3}.
        \item \cref{fig:example2,fig:example4};
              \Cref{fig:example2,fig:example4}.
        \item \cref{fig:example,fig:example2,fig:example4};
              \Cref{fig:example,fig:example2,fig:example4}.
    \end{itemize}
    
% streamlining the remaining code...
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:example} 
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:example2}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:example3}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:example4}
\end{document}


Thank you for your help, this is a great solution, but this is not for a formal publication and I would prefer to keep the bold font both "figure" and the reference "1". If it's possible and keep the above results (hyperlinks), it would be perfect

@MichaelRosalesVilca - Please see the addendum I posted. Speaking for myself (who else?!), I would not engage in this bold-facing exercise.

thanks for your support, but note that it returns to the initial situation where "figure" doesn't have an hyperlink. I've been trying to modify the code of the cleveref package but I don't know enough to do that
My second try was to use \hyperref command but it doesn't seem working fine
\hyperref[#1]{\color{green!50!black}\textbf{figura}~#2\textbf{#1}#3}} 
If you have another idea, I would really appreciate reading it

update
I revised the documentation of cleveref package and I note that if I put the #2 and #3 around "figure", this gets the same characteristic that #1. The case is similar for \crefrangeformat and \crefmultiformat

@MichaelRosalesVilca - Good catch. I've updated the code shown aboveto move the #2 markers (or #3 markers, in the case of \[cC]refrangeformat, to before the \textbf{[fF]igura[s]} chunks.
